# Error while deploying environment variable to firebase

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, firebase-cli

When I am triying to add environment variable to firebase, I have the following error when doing `firebase deploy --only functions`

> Error: Cannot understand what targets to deploy. Check that you specified valid targets if you used the --only or --except flag. Otherwise, check your firebase.json to ensure that your project is initialized for the desired features

I can't understand why i have this error (I previously managed to add environment variable on the same project)

Note : I have also tried add environment variable to a newly created project so my firebase.json is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Check that where you are running the command `firebase deploy --only functions` in `command prompt` is under the same directory as your `functions` folder.

Comment: I have no functions folder because i am just using hosting

Comment: If you have no Cloud Functions, why are you trying to deploy `--only functions`? As far as I know, only Cloud Functions have access to environment variables.